# Symfony2: PdfBundle table to have no border

Tags: symfony, pdf-generation

With PdfBundle installed and working otherwise just fine, I am unable to find a method to turn off the table border or set cell padding.  In the template `<table border.type="none">` has no effect and creating a stylesheet template with

```
<stylesheet>
    <td padding="2px"></td>
</stylesheet>
```

similarly has no effect.

Further testing has revealed that the stylesheet is not found.  I've posted an issue with the author of the bundle at github rather than burden SO.

Comment: An acceptable alternate solution would be to create columns of unequal width.  Using `<div width=...` inside the `<column-layout...` does not create unequal width columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of PdfBundle declares there is no bug in finding the stylesheet,  but none of the iterations I've tried work.  An explicit, detailed example would be nice.

The only available solution to no border, for now at least, is to do `<td border.type="none">` for every `<td>` in the table!